# Customizing wp_nav_menu to Replace Menu URLs with Loop-Generated Anchors?

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a single-page WordPress theme that utilizes Reveal.js, so all of the sections are indexed on the same page (www.example.com/#/, www.example.com/#/1, www.example.com/#/2...). As each section is its own post, I am unable to use WP's built in menu functionality.

I was able to generate a functioning menu through a loop:
>

> ```
> <?php $args= array(
>         'post_type' => 'slide',
>         );
>         $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
>         $i = 0;
>         while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
>             echo '<li><a href="#/'. $i . '">';
>                     the_title();
>                     echo '</a></li>';
>                     $i++;
>                 endwhile;
>             wp_reset_postdata();
>         ?>
> ```

The problem with this is that my menu displays in the order that the posts were created. Is there a way to utilize wp_nav_menu (so users can easily customize), but replace part of the url with the looped iterations that reflect each section/post? Is there a different way in which I can simply pull the order of a menu and apply it to this loop?

I want to be able to automate this and not simply hardcode the data in.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: why not use `wp_nav_menu` with the appearance -> menus that way user can input how the menus show up..

Comment: I am confused by what you mean... because I want to do. However, with that, users can either create a menu in Appearance with the slides in the order of their choosing (in which the links go to the unique permalink of that slide, which is bad) or they can create a custom menu in Appearance (in which users would need to input the hashes and index numbers to each link, which is tedious and depends on post order). 


I want to automate this process to where it would be the easiest on the user.